# Connect two queries using join or any other method?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using two tables. One is [Receipt Cash Book] (RCB) & other one is Banking Cheques. Some Records insert from RCB & Insert into BC. I wrote following queries to view records in RCB table

```
SELECT RCBBankCode, RCBBranchCode, RCBChequeDate, RCBChequeNo, SUM(RCBOrginalAmount) AS ChqAmount
FROM         dbo.[Receipt Cash Book]
WHERE     (RCBLocationCode = '01') AND (RCBReceiptDate = CONVERT(date, '20200918', 112)) AND (RCBCancelTag = 0) AND (RCBPaymentCode <> 'CASH')
GROUP BY RCBBankCode, RCBBranchCode, RCBChequeDate, RCBChequeNo
```

And I wrote following query to view records in BC table

```
    SELECT     DepQChqBank, DepQChqBranch, DepQChqDate, DepQChqNo, CASE WHEN EXISTS
                          (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQDate, [Banking Cheques].DepQBank, [Banking Cheques].DepQBranch, [Banking Cheques].DepQAccountNo, 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQRLocation, [Banking Cheques].DepQRDate, [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBank, 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBranch, [Banking Cheques].DepQChqDate, [Banking Cheques].DepQChqNo
                            FROM          [Banking Cheques] INNER JOIN
                                                   [Receipt Cash Book] ON [Banking Cheques].DepQRLocation = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBLocationCode AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQRDate = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBReceiptDate AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBank = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBBankCode AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBranch = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBBranchCode AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqDate = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBChequeDate AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqNo = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBChequeNo
                            WHERE      ([Banking Cheques].DepQBank = '7010') AND ([Banking Cheques].DepQBranch = '660') AND 
                                                   ([Banking Cheques].DepQAccountNo = '0000000502') AND ([Banking Cheques].DepQRLocation = '01') AND 
                                                   ([Banking Cheques].DepQRDate = CONVERT(date, '20200918', 112))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Selected
FROM         dbo.[Banking Cheques]
```

from these two queries im getting my expecting result.
1st query result

| RCBBankCode | RCBBranchCode | RCBChequeDate | RCBChequeNo | ChqAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7010 | 002 | 2020-09-13 | 963147 | 5692.50 |
| 7010 | 002 | 2020-09-18 | 123456 | 5376.25 |
| 7056 | 004 | 2020-09-14 | 963789 | 6000.00 |

2nd query result

| DepQChqBank | DepQChqBranch | DepQChqDate | DepQChqNo | Selected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7056 | 004 | 2020-09-14 | 963789 | 1 |

But not from one query. I create view using these two query & wrote a query & I getting my result.

```
    SELECT     vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBBankCode, vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBBranchCode, vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBChequeDate, 
                      vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBChequeNo, vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.ChqAmount, ISNULL(vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.Selected, 0) 
                      AS Selected
FROM         vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts ON vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.DepQRDate = vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBReceiptDate AND 
                      vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.DepQRLocation = vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBLocationCode AND 
                      vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.DepQChqBank = vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBBankCode AND 
                      vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.DepQChqBranch = vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBBranchCode AND 
                      vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.DepQChqDate = vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBChequeDate AND 
                      vwRCB_BankingChequesSelect.DepQChqNo = vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBChequeNo
WHERE     (vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBLocationCode = '01') AND (vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBReceiptDate = CONVERT(date, '20200918', 112))
ORDER BY vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBBankCode, vwRCB_BankingSelectReceipts.RCBBranchCode
```

The Result for the above query is

| RCBBankCode | RCBBranchCode | RCBChequeDate | RCBChequeNo | ChqAmount | Selected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7010 | 002 | 2020-09-13 | 963147 | 5692.50 | 0 |
| 7010 | 002 | 2020-09-18 | 123456 | 5376.25 | 0 |
| 7056 | 004 | 2020-09-14 | 963789 | 6000.00 | 1 |

But I cannot pass parameter values(hardcode values were parameterized values)  to view.

Can you please help me to solve this problem by combining above two queries.

Comment: Use this code I did not optimize it .. I just made changes to your code

And one problem is that your code is not optimized. Work more ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code
I did not optimize it .. I just made changes to your code

And one problem is that your code is not optimized. Work more ways

```
select *
from 
    (SELECT RCBBankCode, RCBBranchCode, RCBChequeDate, RCBChequeNo, SUM(RCBOrginalAmount) AS ChqAmount
    FROM         dbo.[Receipt Cash Book]
    WHERE     (RCBLocationCode = '01') AND (RCBReceiptDate = CONVERT(date, '20200918', 112)) AND (RCBCancelTag = 0) AND (RCBPaymentCode <> 'CASH')
    GROUP BY RCBBankCode, RCBBranchCode, RCBChequeDate, RCBChequeNo) Query1 RIGHT JOIN


    (SELECT     DepQChqBank, DepQChqBranch, DepQChqDate, DepQChqNo, CASE WHEN EXISTS
                          (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQDate, [Banking Cheques].DepQBank, [Banking Cheques].DepQBranch, [Banking Cheques].DepQAccountNo, 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQRLocation, [Banking Cheques].DepQRDate, [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBank, 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBranch, [Banking Cheques].DepQChqDate, [Banking Cheques].DepQChqNo
                            FROM          [Banking Cheques] INNER JOIN
                                                   [Receipt Cash Book] ON [Banking Cheques].DepQRLocation = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBLocationCode AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQRDate = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBReceiptDate AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBank = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBBankCode AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqBranch = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBBranchCode AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqDate = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBChequeDate AND 
                                                   [Banking Cheques].DepQChqNo = [Receipt Cash Book].RCBChequeNo
                            WHERE      ([Banking Cheques].DepQBank = '7010') AND ([Banking Cheques].DepQBranch = '660') AND 
                                                   ([Banking Cheques].DepQAccountNo = '0000000502') AND ([Banking Cheques].DepQRLocation = '01') AND 
                                                   ([Banking Cheques].DepQRDate = CONVERT(date, '20200918', 112))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Selected
        FROM         dbo.[Banking Cheques] ) Query2 
                                                        ON Query1.DepQRDate = Query2.RCBReceiptDate AND 
                                                           Query1.DepQRLocation = Query2.RCBLocationCode AND 
                                                           Query1.DepQChqBank = Query2.RCBBankCode AND 
                                                           Query1.DepQChqBranch = Query2.RCBBranchCode AND 
                                                           Query1.DepQChqDate = Query2.RCBChequeDate AND 
                                                           Query1.DepQChqNo = Query2.RCBChequeNo


WHERE     (Query2.RCBLocationCode = '01') AND (Query2.RCBReceiptDate = CONVERT(date, '20200918', 112))
ORDER BY Query2.RCBBankCode, Query2.RCBBranchCode
```